# Accessing the arguments of a function passed as an argument to another function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm writing a function that takes another function as an argument. Inside the function another function is called that checks if the given function has been called with that particular function. If it has, it doesn't run the function and just returns the data that has already been ran before.

My question is, how do I access the arguments for that function which was given as an argument? (I know that memoize is already a function from underscore, I'm just trying to write it for myself to better understand altering functions with other functions).

```
var memoize = function(func) {
    //variable to store arguments : results which have been computed
    var arguments = {};
    return function() {
      //check if argument for func is in arguments
      // if it is, access argument and return result
      //if not, run the function and update the arguments object with the argument (key) and the result (value)
        //return the result
    }
  };
```

Comment: Why not look at the underscore code for memoize?  https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/modules/memoize.js

Comment: Yes I have looked there, but I what is that has method that they are importing?

Comment: It's the `_has.js` module in the same github folder as the memoize.js module.  https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/modules/_has.js